# Transactions to a SQL Server database from multiple application using NHibernate created with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, ssms

I've created an C# application using NHibernate to select and insert to a SQL Server database created in Database Design Studio Lite and managed with SQL Server Management Studio.

My problem is that when I have the application running on several workstations, the database is not safe for multiple transaction like it is not "thread safe", don't know what to call the problem.

What is simplest way to make my database safe from multiple transactions? I've tried to set "Restrict Access" to SINGLE_USER mode, but that locks the database to the first application that connects to it and leaves all the other applications to fail.

From SQL Server Management Studio I only create tables. I do not select, insert or update the database. All of the this is done from the applications.

I hope that these information I've provided is enough to help me out. Otherwise I'll post some more :)

**EDIT**

Found out that NHibernate uses the SessionFactory so all transactions are safe :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using actual transactions when querying, adding, and modifying records?

```
using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
   // query or submit changes to session here, calling tx.Commit() at the end if you make changes
}
```

The default isolation should restrict to read committed, so queries should not be returning any modifications that have not been fully committed yet.

Comment: No i haven't. Didn't though of it :), but what does the code snippet do? And where can I fínd SessionFactory?